# how can I sign a typedData with @safe-global/protocol-kit?

Tags: gnosis-safe, signature

how can I sign a typedData with `@safe-global/protocol-kit` api?

I have objects like this `const data = { domain, types, message }`

Comment: Please specific requirements or constraints for signing the typedData with @safe-global/protocol-kit API, such as any particular parameters or configurations needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [this guide](https://docs.safe.global/smart-account-signatures) to use typed data with the protocol kit, specifically, how to [create](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#sign-the-message), [sign](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#sign-the-message), [publish](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#publish-the-signed-message) and [verify](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#validate-the-signature) typed messages.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Comment: thx a lot, I have find solutions